# TypeError: Cannot find default value for object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have a google ads script which is failing with the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.
```

It seems fairly cryptic so im not sure what its referring to.

This is the line that its failing on:

```js
var adOperation = adGroup.newAd().expandedTextAdBuilder()
  .newAd()
  .expandedTextAdBuilder()
  .withHeadline1(expandedTextAd.getHeadline1())
  .withHeadline2(expandedTextAd.getHeadline2())
  .withDescription1(expandedTextAd.getDescription1())
  .withPath1(expandedTextAd.getPath1())
  .withPath2(expandedTextAd.getPath2())
  .withTrackingTemplate(expandedTextAd.getTrackingTemplate())
  .withFinalUrl(expandedTextAd.getFinalUrl())
  .build(adGroup);
```

I've checked adGroup is set and it is, not sure where to go from here.

Update:

I split the line in to each method call and the line which is failing is line 1

```js
> var adOperation = adGroup
.newAd()
.expandedTextAdBuilder()
```

Comment: It will be difficult to decipher this without the full code. `adGroup` itself is no built in object, so you need to acquire it through a [selector](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_adgroupselector.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to post the full code as its business sensitive. Whats strange is that I can log the complete adGroup object prior to this error occurring. Do you know of an instance where this error could occur? I can't remember ever experiencing this before and there is very little examples online of it.

Comment: The current information is too little to provide proper pointers. I would recommend to provide the code that creates and alters the `adGroup` variabele at the very least. Maybe try to post your code while masking business sensitive parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours head scratching, I fixed this by removing `adGroup` from the `.build()` method. `build()` doesn't take any parameters and I'm not sure why I was passing it. Still a very strange error.

```js
var adOperation = adGroup
  .newAd()
  .expandedTextAdBuilder()
  .withHeadline1(expandedTextAd.getHeadline1())
  .withHeadline2(expandedTextAd.getHeadline2())
  .withDescription1(expandedTextAd.getDescription1())
  .withPath1(expandedTextAd.getPath1())
  .withPath2(expandedTextAd.getPath2())
  .withTrackingTemplate(expandedTextAd.getTrackingTemplate())
  .withFinalUrl(expandedTextAd.getFinalUrl())
  .build();
```

I would recommend anyone trying to solve anything similar to unchain the method calls and debug each call line by line.